# How to (Python Iterate from a json array of objects)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, object

What is the best way to iterate from an array of objects and use that data to update selected rows in a database table ?

I wanted to update data from the database where `id = tasklist`,

`id` from the json I've provided below, and set 
`attached_document_ins.is_viewed = checked`  value from the json with that ID .

for example, if `id == 35` then `attached_document_ins.is_viewed = True` cause the checked value of id 35 is True.

What is the best algo for that ?

I have provided my code below.

```
#Code

def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        print("Response Data :" , data)
        try:


            attached_document_ins = DocumentTask.objects.filter(id=tasklist_id)
            for attached_document_ins in attached_document_ins:
                attached_document_ins.is_viewed = True
            attached_document_ins.save()
            return Response("Success", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except DocumentTask.DoesNotExist:
            return Response("Failed.", status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## Json(data)

```
{
   'tasklist':[
      {
         'files':[

         ],
         'checked':True,
         'company':6,
         'task':'s',
         'applicant':159,
         'id':35
      },
      {
         'files':[

         ],
         'checked':True,
         'company':6,
         'task':'ss',
         'applicant':159,
         'id':36
      },
      {
         'files':[

         ],
         'checked':True,
         'company':6,
         'task':'sss',
         'applicant':159,
         'id':37
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
for task in data['tasklist']:
    if task['checked']:
        document = DocumentTask.objects.get(id=task['id'])
        document.is_viewed = True
        document.save()
```